# Javascript: How to call javascript function in html

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in coding. I have dynamic product price. Price is like 40000, 60000, 654000. I want to make them in [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) like 4 Lac, 6.5 Lac, and 1 cr. 
I found this code on stackoverflow

```
function numDifferentiation(val) {
    if(val >= 10000000) val = (val/10000000).toFixed(2) + ' Cr';
    else if(val >= 100000) val = (val/100000).toFixed(2) + ' Lac';
    else if(val >= 1000) val = (val/1000).toFixed(2) + ' K';
    return val;
}
```

I tried `document.write(numDifferentiation(<?php echo $row['price'];));` but its not working.

Comment: That code should throw some pretty obvious PHP syntax errors. (It also makes me question why you are using JavaScript instead of PHP in the first place).

Comment: try document.write(numDifferentiation('<?php echo $row['price'];?>'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
function numDifferentiation(val) {
    if(val >= 10000000) val = (val/10000000).toFixed(2) + ' Cr';
    else if(val >= 100000) val = (val/100000).toFixed(2) + ' Lac';
    else if(val >= 1000) val = (val/1000).toFixed(2) + ' K';
    return val;
}
document.write(numDifferentiation(<?php echo $row['price'];?>));
</script>
```

you missed the closing php tag '?>'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i tried <script>document.write(numDifferentiation(<?php echo $row['msp'];?>));</script>. still not working

Comment: Thanks it working. I think my mistake was i am not defining function every time.

Comment: do you have any error log? for javascript or for php?

Comment: Consol Error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: numDifferentiation is not defined"

Comment: i used function on main.js file then call it every time. its not working if i call every time before document.write() then its work.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you php script has syntax error it should be closed when open.
 like below

```
document.write(numDifferentiation('<?php echo $row['price'];?>'));]
```

you can you a html tag and pass access that html tag using id like this `$('id').val(numDifferentiation('<?php echo $row['price'];?>'))`

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
    function numDifferentiation(val) {
        if(val >= 10000000) val = (val/10000000).toFixed(2) + ' Cr';
        else if(val >= 100000) val = (val/100000).toFixed(2) + ' Lac';
        else if(val >= 1000) val = (val/1000).toFixed(2) + ' K';
        return val;
    }
    document.write(numDifferentiation(290000));
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

working code 
you can also try

```
document.write(numDifferentiation(<?php echo $row['price'];?>));
```

becouse you are not closing php tag

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not your javascript function, it looks to works fine.

First, you have to close your Php Tag

Change:
`numDifferentiation(<?php echo $row['price'];)`

To: `numDifferentiation(<?php echo $row['price']; ?>)`

Now, diferent from Php, in JavaScript, you'll always change an existing element, so...

Create an element in HTML: `<span id="mySpan"></span>`

And just change the element's content using JavaScript

`document.querySelector('#mySpan').innerHTML = numDifferentiation(<?php echo $row['price'];)`

It is suppose to works, try and if you have any error don't hesitate in ask more help :)